# Vue integration - multi-inline-editor on one page

Tags: vuejs3, tinymce, editor, inline

I try to realize the case in Vue3, when there are many inline-editing DIVs on one page.
And all of editors has the same target HTML-elemnent where toolbar to be placed on editing.
Unfortunately I can not find any info for this case. No in your docs, no in SOF and Inet...

That DIVs are part of a Vue3 component template (one DIV per component). And that DIVs has the same CSS-class ("item-text" for example).

If I try include to template of MyComponent the Tiny Editor itself (instead of simple HTML DIV tag) and include several (may be 100) of MyComponents to the page template, then the same count of editor instances are produced on this page and every of them produces own toolbar (I see them all in dev console of browser). So, I think it's the wrong way.

If I include DIV with class "item-text" to template of MyComponent, and place to the page template one Editor instance after all several MyComponents, and init Editor with this config object:
`{ selector: ".item-text", inline: true, fixed_toolbar_container_target: this.editorToolBar }`
(this.editorToolBar - ref to HTML-element where the toolbar to be placed on editing), there are two questions:

1. How to set and get (so, to edit) the html of every DIV separately? How to bind v-model for Editor component correctly?
2. Why if I use a selector in init object, the toolbar is not placed to fixed_toolbar_container_target, but is popups near the text?

I expect the way to use TinyMCE Editor with Vue3 components to edit the text in them inline and separatly when several componets contains the text to be edited. And Editor must show its toolbar in the place that I want (not popup near the text to be edited).